# Problems when using fgets and strcat

Tags: c

I am having some problems while using `fgets` and `strcat` (I tried to replace the `fgets` into `scanf` and the program worked). It seems the `strcat` is not working.

```
char name[256];
char text[256];

fgets(name,250,stdin);
strcat(name,".txt");
printf("%s\n",name);
```

The output is (in separate lines):

```
d
.txt
```

Comment: You need to remove the new line from name after `fgets`

Comment: Take a look at [my answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36341266/434551). While the questions are different, the solution is exactly the same.

Comment: If `strcat` weren't working, you wouldn't see `.txt` in the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the newline from the input. Like this:

```
fgets(name, 250, stdin);
char *p = strchr(name, '\n');
if (p)
    *p = '\0';
strcat(name, ".txt");
```

Obviously you'd want to add some error checking there but this demonstrates the idea.

Comment: This assumes a newline is in `name` which may not always be the case. Maybe use `strchr`.

Answer (score 1):

because `'\n'` is also consumed in your `fgets` function, it will be displayed like that. You can use `scanf` instead for simplicity:

```
int main() {
   char name[256];
   char text[256];

   scanf("%250s",name);
   strcat(name,".txt");
   printf("%s\n",name);
}
```

Comment: Note: `scanf("%s")` only reads until the next space, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf for details.

Comment: @RolandIllig that is right, since the example shows something like a filename "d.txt" it is not viable to catch the space and it doesn't require extra functions to drop the final "\n" either. However if the code's intention is really for getting a hole string including space, tabs ,... then you are right

Answer (score 1):

Using the rarely-used function `strcspn`, this becomes simple and error-prone:

```
if (fgets(name, 250, stdin) != NULL) {
  strcpy(name + strcspn(name, "\n"), ".txt");
  ...
}
```

The `strcspn` function counts the number of characters that are *not* `\n`; the c in strcspn means *complement*.
Therefore, no matter whether or not the name contains a newline or not, the `.txt` will always be added at the correct position.